# Javsacript - Scroll Bar within Browser Window

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

This website has a scroll bar within the browser window scroll bar.
When you scroll (if there are several results that exceed the limit that can be shown), it will load more when you scroll to the bottom.
I am trying to scrape this website (I am looking to use javascript to scroll down to the bottom), but unable to move this scroll bar down. Any ideas?

I tried the following javascript unsuccessfully:

```
function ExecuteScript() 
{
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
}
```

Here is the website:  https://jobs.fscj.edu
(Go to the website, then click on 'View All Jobs')

Comment: If my answer is correct, please mark it as a solution for future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use a `window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);` because you don't want scroll an entire website (window) but just a certain div.

I'm able to scroll a job list in your sample site in both directions - up and down - with a below code:

```
document.getElementById('win0divHRS_AGNT_RSLT_I$grid$0').scrollTop = 7000;
```

The `win0divHRS_AGNT_RSLT_I$grid$0` is a container with jobs which you want to scroll.